# I need a rather basic Regex.Match syntax - to identify a text line with 2 numbers separated by 2 spaces

Tags: regex, syntax

I am a complete rookie at interpreting this syntax... bear with me.

The first number is expected to be after 2 spaces (3rd character), it can be 1 to 5 digits
The second number will be just after 2 more spaces (and will be 4 digits or 6 digits only)
Currently we use this line, but it is picking up numbers embedded inside of other words.

```
 Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"\s*\d+\s*(\d{6}|\d{4})"); 
 if (m.Groups.Count > 1)
    ; code to save it as a line element
```

It needs to capture all of these number sets with the if stastement

```
1  000233
223  1239
2678  0289
17  002394
```

And ignore these lines

```
P_740008_FLT_FG == AFL001
X_234_FLOAT == AFL022
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based off the answer from 'The fourth bird'
This was the best solution I ended up, thanks to the clear explanations provided:

```
       Regex.Match(line, @"^\s*\d+\s+(\d{6}|\d{4})\b");
```

The key elements I believe were -

- adding the ^ to signify the 1st # is at the beginning of the line,
- second was the \b at the end to identify the 2nd # ends at a word boundary.
- The \s* at the beginning allows 0 or more spaces at the line start, this can happen
  when it grows to larger 5 digit line numbers, and
- finally the 2nd \s+ identified at least 1 required space before the next grouped #.

This appears to be working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like C#. In that case you can use `[0-9]` to match a digit from  0-9 as `\d` matches digits from other languages as well.

Reading the requirements, the pattern would be starting with 2 spaces before and after the 1-5 digits.

To match 1-5 digits, you could use a quantifier for the first part `[0-9]{1,5}`

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

```
  [0-9]{1,5}  (?:[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{4})\b
```

To match the examples, you could also start the pattern with a word boundary, and end the pattern with a word boundary as well to prevent partial matches.

```
\b[0-9]{1,5}  (?:[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{4})\b
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c5%7d++%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7b6%7d%7c%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%29%5cb&i=1++000233%0d%0a223++1239%0d%0a2678++0289%0d%0a17++002394%0d%0a%0d%0aP_740008_FLT_FG%09%3d%3d+AFL001%0d%0a++++X_234_FLOAT+%3d%3d+AFL022)

You can omit the capture group and check for the length. Instead you can use `.Success` on the Match:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"\b[0-9]{1,5}  (?:[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{4})\b");

if (m.Success) {
                
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I actually did try your suggestion later that night and from the explanation and example you provided I was able to work out my own solution. 
At first I thought your code did not work at all, later realizing it only had not worked in my context, of looking for a group match success. It turns out our code is designed to focus in on the group and therefore that part of our regex.match was required.   

I will provide the solution I ended up with in an answer post, thanks to your explanation I was able to figure it out..